# Can a webpage's title be accessed before the page is done loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, web

So I am building a Chrome plugin that needs access to the DOM of the user's visible page for a variety of purposes.  I also need to use the title of the page, but it seems unnecessary to wait until the entire page has loaded via:

```
$(document).on("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    onLoad();
});
```

Is there anyway I can access the title of the page (as it is already viewable in the browser) before the page finishes loading?

The reason I would like to do this is that my extension sends (& waits for the response of) an API call (relying only on the page title) so I would like to start this process as quickly as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually tried it, but if the page `header` is already loaded at the time that your extension script runs, the following *should* give you the title:

```
document.head.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText
// EDIT: Or I guess you could just use document.title
```

Some websites might modify the page title with a script, so it's probably a good idea to verify the title once the page has fully loaded as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing `<script>` element including `document.title="title"` before `<title>` element . This should set `title` of `document` before `body` is loaded

```js
document.body.textContent = document.title
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  document.title = "def"
</script>
  <title>abc</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```